# How to pass filtered data to Datatables on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5, datatables

In the app I'm working on, we have two data sources: MySQL and Elasticsearch. The ES has, in rough terms, a copy of MySQL data for better performance. I built a management panel that accesses the MySQL directly. And this was OK for writing operations and retrieving a single item. However, when I try to list and filter lots of records it's very slow, causing time-outs. Then, I'm updating just the listing part to get the data from ES instead of MySQL.

The panel was built on [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) and we're using the [Datatables plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/) to display the data. To bind Datatables to the back-end, we have the [Datatables package for Laravel](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/).

With the following controller action, and when not applying any filter, it works fine:

```
public function data(Elasticsearch $elastic, Request $request)
{
    $query = [];
    $cols = [];
    if ($request->has('columns')) {
        foreach ($request->get('columns') as $column) {
            $cols[] = $column['name'];
            if (!empty($column['search']['value'])) {
                $query[] = sprintf('%s:%s', $column['name'], $column['search']['value']);
            }
        }
    }

    $from = (int) $request->get('start');
    $size = (int) $request->get('length');
    $sort = [];
    if ($request->has('order')) {
        foreach ($request->get('order') as $order) {
            $sort[] = [ $cols[$order['column']] => $order['dir'] ];
        }
    } else {
        $sort[] = [ 'name' => 'asc' ];
    }
    $args = [
        'index' => 'acme',
        'type' => 'user',
        'from' => $from ?: 0,
        'size' => $size ?: 10,
        'sort' => $sort,
    ];
    if (count($query) > 0) {
        $args['q'] = implode(' AND ', $query);
    }

    $response = $elastic->search($args);
    $data = [];
    $total = 0;

    if (!empty($response['hits'])) {
        $total = $response['hits']['total'];
        $data = array_map(function ($hit) {
            return $hit['_source'];
        }, $response['hits']['hits']);
    }

    return Datatables::of(collect($data))
        ->skipPaging()
        ->setTotalRecords($total)
        ->make(true);
}
```

The Javascript that triggers the table rendering looks like this:

```
$('#users-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('user.data') !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { data: 'type', name: 'type' },
        { data: 'status', name: 'status' }
    ]
});
```

The issues appear when I try to search or filter the table by some column. The pagination stops to work. I guess that's because I'm filtering the dataset before passing it to Datatables, in `Datatables::of()`. I know I can retrieve the entire dataset from ES and let Datatables do the filtering and sorting data, but I'll probably end up with time and memory usage issues. We have millions of documents indexed.

I tried to override the global search using an empty function (`->filter(function () {})`), but it didn't work. The pagination breaks when I add this, showing only a single page even if the total of records is set to a big value.

Comment: Have you tried [Overriding Global Search](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/collection/custom-filter)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, yes. That's what I tried when passing an empty function to filter. Since I'm already filtering the data in ES, I may have this function empty. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented on Gyrocode's answer, I've found a way to make it work the way I wanted. I guess there are more elegant ways to do it, but this one worked.

Since the Datatables library I'm using takes the current request to sort and filter the data, I've looked into the source code for a way to use an empty request. I ended up finding that is possible to instantiate the engine passing the request I want.

Here's what I did:

```
use Yajra\Datatables\Engines\CollectionEngine;
use Yajra\Datatables\Request as DatatablesRequest;

// ...

return value(new CollectionEngine(collect($data), new DatatablesRequest()))
    ->setTotalRecords($total)
    ->make‌​(true);
```

This way, the lib uses the data as it is and don't do any kind of filtering or sorting.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the Laravel DataTables source code, there is undocumented [`overrideGlobalSearch()`](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/6.0/src/Engines/BaseEngine.php#L785-L798) method, see the definition below. Last parameter is a flag that determines whether default global search should be performed.

```
/**
 * Update flags to disable global search
 *
 * @param  callable $callback
 * @param  mixed $parameters
 * @param  bool $autoFilter
 */
public function overrideGlobalSearch(callable $callback, $parameters, $autoFilter = false)
{
}
```

You theoretically should be able to do the following:

```
$datatables = Datatables::of(collect($data))
    ->skipPaging()
    ->setTotalRecords($total);

$datatables->overrideGlobalSearch(function(){ }, null);

return $datatables->make(true);
```

Also you would need to reset parameters holding column search values so that DataTables does not perform column search by default.

In addition to that, make sure that your `$total` variable holds total number of records **before** filtering.

Comment: Since `overrideGlobalSearch` is called from `filter` method, my attempt to use `->filter(function () {})` has a similar effect. And, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The pagination breaks when I add that. Also, you can't add `overrideGlobalSearch` to the method chain, because it doesn't return the engine instance. Thx!

Comment: Just to let you know, I've tried as you suggested, this way: `$datatables = Datatables::of(collect($data))->skipPaging(); $datatables->overrideGlobalSearch(function(){ }, null); return $datatables->setTotalRecords($total)->make(true);`. And got the same result as using `->filter()`. BTW, sorry for the single line code.

Comment: @GustavoStraube, you're right about not being able to chain `overrideGlobalSearch`, corrected the answer. Did you read the part about resetting column search request parameters and the total count vs. filtered records count?

Comment: Starting with your answer, I've found a way to achieve what I wanted: `return value(new \Yajra\Datatables\Engines\CollectionEngine(collect($data), new \Yajra\Datatables\Request()))->setTotalRecords($total)->make(true);`. I'm calling the `CollectionEngine` constructor directly and passing an empty request to it. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do it, but it's working.